# Google "Play Music" app constantly running!

Tags: google-play-music, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Why is Google Play Music constantly running on my galaxy s4? I don't use any music app.

Comment: I know we're not supposed to ask for clarification, but we need more details. Where is it running? If it's in your notification bar, there's an 'X' you can press to close it. If it's in your recent apps you can swipe it away. If it's taking up your battery usage, it might be syncing in the background for some reason and you can turn off sync for it in your google account settings (Settings -> Accounts -> Google).

Comment: @HenriSweers sure we shall ask in those cases -- but not in the answers :) Pat: "Why" questions of this kind are hard to answer. I took your question to really mean "how can I stop that". If I was right with this, see my answer below :)

Comment: None of the answers below answers the question. WHY is GPM contantly running? The question does not requests "How to disable it" but WHY.

Comment: In my case the  Play Music app leaves an icon **permanently in the notification bar**.  I can't get rid of it by stopping the music, nor by triangle-backing out of the app, nor by square-X closing the app.  Annoying because I try to keep the notification bar clear so it means "stuff I gotta do."  I have a Moto X 2nd Gen with Android Lollipop.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't use any music app (especially not the one in question), there's an easy cure:

1. Go to *Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*
2. Go to the *All* tab
3. Scroll the list until you find *Google Play Music*
4. Tap the entry
5. On the screen which opens on the tap, you'll find a button labeled <kbd>Disable</kbd> -- push it.

If the <kbd>Disable</kbd> button is grayed out (and cannot be pushed), you might need to first <kbd>Force Stop</kbd> the app, and <kbd>Uninstall updates</kbd>. If you later decide you want to use the app, and enable it again, updates will be applied once more -- so no worries for that.

Done: You've successfully disabled the *Google Play Music* app. It will no longer be available in your apps drawer, and should no longer run automatically either. Works fine for me, also for *Google Play Books* and *Movies*. Another nice side-effect: Your device will no longer bother you for any updates of those (disabled) apps -- which might even help you saving your data plan for better things :)

Comment: I searched this kind of solution for months ! Thanks for the 'uninstall updates' tip.

Comment: I had to unistnall the updates, but then I was allowed to disable it. 
google play music crashes other apps I was running at the same time. 
Great post.

Answer (score 1):

And for a long term solution, please consider leaving a review of the app ([play store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music)).

Certainly, some of the very short, thoughtless reviews that we see on the play store are of no use, but if you've made a decent attempt to resolve your concern (e.g. by reading the description provided for the app  ) and are still not satisfied, then voice your concerns.

And I think the bar should even higher for a pre-installed app.

Answer (score -1):

I have a galaxy s2 with sprint as provider. The Google Play music app came pre bundled with the phone. After noticing that it was regularly opening itself and showing up in the "applications running" widget, I began to research the issue. First I attempted (as advised) to remove updates. This doesn't work, as the app just auto updates itself again with no option to disable this. The app CAN NOT BE UNINSTALLED. I called sprint and was told that since it came bundled with the phone, it could not be uninstalled because other features of the phone rely on parts  the google play music app. They essentially told me that there was nothing I could do about it, and to keep updating it in the hope that they will eventually fix the auto starting bug. I also tried installing other music players in the hope slim hope that this may fix the problem, but this (as expected) didn't remedy the issue. In summary, after extensive internet research on the issue, and a call to my provider, my conclusion is as follows: It still opens itself, it cant be uninstalled, and the update rollback just re updates itself without the ability to stop this (on the galaxy s2 anyway). Looks like we're stuck with this one and can only wait and hope that google fixes the issue in one of the updates. Call me a cynic , but I tend to doubt google is in any hurry to PREVENT the running of one of their apps. The Sprint Samsung galaxy s2 comes completely inundated with bundled google software. I have been a loyal sprint customer for over 5 years, and this, in addition to the sudden and drastic decrease in sprint's signal and gps strength is just another indicator that they are going down the tubes. Hopefully sprint & google get their collective acts together and fix these issues. I'll keep researching, and post if I find a solution.

Comment: This would be a decent answer if it were a little less "rant-y".

Comment: Agreed, it was a combination of factual info with an overtone of "rant" included for the purpose of insuring readers that there at present is nothing they can do to solve this save pressure the provider to fix this. I never post on these sites and am not familiar with the etiquette